# How to view the http request created by an jquery ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, http

Is there a way to view the raw http request that a jquery ajax request is sending to the server?

I am seeing different behaviors on some different devices with regards to an ajax request.  If I can view the raw http request I might be able to diagnose the issue...This is mostly related to mobile devices so normal tools (fiddler,fire bug, chrome dev tools) are not available.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jqXHR object returned by `$.ajax()` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

**EDIT**

See an example here http://jsfiddle.net/mattydsw/j8TSg/ I used prettyprint.js for presenting object.

Comment: Is there a way to get the raw http request from this data?

Comment: You know url and data you send. More you wish to see is status code, it's in field "status". What more do you want to get? See the example and methods in `obj`

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark can help you track network usage
so you ll be able to check all http data transfers (ajax or not) using filters.

You may be able to log http request directly on the server (WS can listen on localhost)